# angular ng-click works from the second click

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-modal, angularjs-ng-click

I am using `ng-click` to open a modal and for calling a func:

```
<a class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editWorkerModal" ng-click="workerInfo(worker.id); professionsInfo()"> 
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit white"></i>
</a>
```

Now the modal opened, the `professionsInfo()` function ran, but doesn't work well in the first time I click on it.

This is the `professionInfo()` func:

```
$scope.professionsInfo = function () {
    $http({
        url: '/SafetyManager/professions',
        method: "GET",
    }).success(function (response) {
        $scope.professions = response;
        for(var i = 0, len1=$scope.info.professions.length; i<len1; i++) {
            for(var n=0, len2=$scope.professions.length; n<len2; n++) {
                if($scope.info.professions[i].id == $scope.professions[n].id)
                    $scope.professions[n].disabled = true;
            }
        }       
    });
};
```

The func returns correct data from the server, and update it on `$scope.professions` (I know that because the data shown in dropdown list)
but the for loop fails with the error from the browser:

> "TypeError: Cannot read property 'professions' of undefined"

Then, if I close the modal and click again it is working fine and there is no error.
But when I refresh, the error returns on the first click and disappears from the second.

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: check once by removing data-target="#editWorkerModal"

Comment: How is this loaded : $scope.info.professions

Comment: Difference between : $scope.professions & $scope.info.professions ? On click $scope.professions gets loaded with response. Where is the other one getting loaded?

Comment: I think the problem is with this `len1=$scope.info.professions.length` in the first for loop. Is `$scope.info` defined? Can you post your `workerInfo(id)` function code? Your error says, angular is unable to read the property `professions` of some quantity since it is undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not call two functions on `ng-click`. Instead include the other function in your `ng-click` function.

For example your html:

```
<a ng-click="workerInfo(worker.id);"> 
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit white"></i>
</a>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.workerInfo = function(workerID) {
  // Do something
  $scope.professionsInfo();
};

$scope.professionsInfo = function() {
  // Do something else
}
```

**EDIT:**

And call your modal open only after you get the success from the `$scope.professionsInfo` http response.

Or even better combine the two and call just one function which does the http request first and then opens the modal window and does the rest of the stuff you need.

Comment: thanks!! when i added professionsInfo into  workerInfo  the problem solved:)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and by calling the method once it's working.

In my page, I have created a factory and kept all ajax call with in it. Now everything is written in controller part, so what is the use of factory and service.